# Gmail blinks and changes font

Tags: gmail

Gmail is set to open when Chrome starts up. As soon as it launches, the font looks good. After a couple of seconds, the page blinks and the font changes.

See the attached image. On the left, the good font.

It only happens on Gmail. On Google search and other sites, font always looks good. Problem started recently.

Using latest Chrome and Windows 7.

[image: before after]

Edit: by inspecting the page, I realized that at first it uses Arial. After the blink, it changed to Roboto. So, why does Roboto look so bad on my screen?